# DBD::Firebird encoding/decoding

Tags: perl, character-encoding, firebird, dbi

In this example, Firebird returns the string undecoded. Have I not set up the database correctly or is this how Firebird works?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use Devel::Peek;
use DBI;

my ( $db, $dbh, $sth, @array );
my $table = 'test_encoding';
my $create = "CREATE TABLE $table ( name varchar(32) )";
my $insert = "INSERT INTO $table ( name ) VALUES ( ? )";
my $select = "SELECT * FROM $table";
my $value = 'ä';

$db = '/home/me/my_firebird_db';
$dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:Firebird:db=$db", 'user', 'password',
    { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1, ib_charset => 'UTF-8' }
);
$sth = $dbh->do( "DROP TABLE $table" );
$sth = $dbh->do( $create );;
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $insert );
$sth->execute( $value );
@array = $dbh->selectrow_array( $select );
Dump $array[0];
say $array[0];
say "";

$db = '/home/me/my_sqlite_db';
$dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:SQLite:db=$db", '', '',
    { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1, sqlite_string_mode => 5 }
);
$sth = $dbh->do( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table" );
$sth = $dbh->do( $create );
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $insert );
$sth->execute( $value );
@array = $dbh->selectrow_array( $select );
Dump $array[0];
say $array[0];
```

Output:

```
SV = PV(0x2105360) at 0x22628a0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x22a37e0 "\303\244"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 10
Ã¤

SV = PV(0x2111470) at 0x2121220
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x1f2fed0 "\303\244"\0 [UTF8 "\x{e4}"]
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 10
ä
```

Comment: I don't know this driver, but what happens if you declare the column as `varchar(32) character set utf8`? What happens if you use `ib_charset => 'UTF8'` (in case the driver expects the Firebird character set name instead of the "normal" character set name)? What is the output of `select RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME from RDB$DATABASE` (which returns the default character set used for a creating column when no character set name is specified explicitly)?

Comment: DBI and all the DBDs I've dealt with work with encoded data. It's weird. Especially when the charset used for communication is known. /// Some DBD have a switch that performs automatic decoding from UTF-8. (e.g. `mysql_enable_utf8mb4`) I don't see one of DBD::Firebird.

Comment: The [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Firebird) mention`ib_enable_utf8`

Comment: @ikegami A lot of Firebird drivers default to a connection character set called `NONE`, which basically means "stores as received, send as stored". That, in combination with using an character set NONE for a column, or a mismatched character set can result in incorrect transliteration of characters.

Comment: Judging by the link supplied by clamp, the `ib_charset` property must be specified in the connection string, so `"dbi:Firebird:db=$db;ib_charset=UTF8"` (note `UTF8`, not `UTF-8`) combined with `ib_enable_utf8 => 1` in the hash.

Comment: Thx, `ib_charset=UTF8` in the dsn and `ib_enable_utf8 => 1` in the hash worked. (I stopped reading the documentation after I have seen `ib_charset=utf8`.) If someone writes that as an answer, I could mark the question as solved.

Comment: Re "*The docs mentionib_enable_utf8*", oops. When I said I don't see one of DBD::Firebird, I was looking at the DSN parameters, not the connect options. Yes, you'd want this. (It requires using UTF-8 for communication , achieved using `ib_charset=utf8`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated by the link to the [documentation of DBD::Firebird](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Firebird) supplied by [clamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10667839/clamp) in the comments, you need to connect using:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:Firebird:db=$db;ib_charset=UTF8", 'user', 'password',
    { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1, ib_enable_utf8 => 1 }
```

That is, the `ib_charset` property must be in the connection string, not in the hash, and its value must be `UTF8` (not `UTF-8`!), and you need to add `ib_enable_utf8` with setting `1` to the hash.

Specifically, [this part](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Firebird#ib_enable_utf8-(driver-specific,-boolean)):

> ##### ib_enable_utf8 (driver-specific, boolean)
>
> Setting this attribute to TRUE will cause any Perl Unicode strings
> supplied as statement parameters to be downgraded to octet sequences
> before passing them to Firebird.
>
> Also, any character data retrieved from the database (CHAR, VARCHAR,
> BLOB sub_type TEXT) will be upgraded to Perl Unicode strings.
>
> **Caveat:** Currently this is supported only if the **ib_charset** DSN parameter is `UTF8`. In the future, encoding and decoding to/from
> arbitrary character set may be implemented.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Firebird:db=database.fdb;ib_charset=UTF8',
>     { ib_enable_utf8 => 1 } );
> ```